# How can a limit become second derivative?

Tags: taylor-expansion, wave-equation

I'm physics student and studying waves. I don't know the mathematical background of this formula.

$\dfrac{\partial u(x+\Delta x,t)}{\partial x} - \dfrac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}\approx\Delta x\dfrac{\partial^2 u(x,t)}{\partial 
x^2}$

I suspect it has to do with Taylor series, but how can a limit become second derivative?

Comment: @Holo It is a step towards derivation of wave formula.

Answer (score 2):

This is actually a standard first derivative, except the function whose derivative is being taken *is itself already a first derivative of another function*.  So the derivatives 'pile up', so to speak.

Comment: @Arthur Sorry Arthur, made mistake. It's fixed now.

Comment: @PMar Makes sense, thank you. But from where does delta x come from?

Comment: @continuity If you divide by $\Delta x$ on both sides, then it's easier to see that the right-hand side is the second derivative, while the right-hand side is the definition of the derivative of $\frac{\partial u(x,t)}{\partial x}$, only it's without the $\lim_{\Delta x\to0}$. So it's an approximation for small $\Delta x$.